# how can i make the loop and change number to string

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int number=0;
    cout<<"enter an number to cumpute";
    cin>>number;
    if(number=0)
        cout<<"0"<<endl;
    for(number>0;51>number;) {
        number--;   
        cout<<"=";
    }
    for(number>10;number%10==0;) {
        cout<<"|";
    }
    for(number>5;number%5==0;) {
        cout<<"+";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

---

(i got textbook called by Y.Daniel Liang. I can not find any thing like this) I have no idea how to make this loop work and I try use "while" and not working either. Should i just cout the "=" "+" "|", or start as string. I hope the output look like this.

---

```
BarPlot – A Simple Bar Graph Plotter:
Input a number in range [0 50] or a negative number to terminate:

| Enter Number: 6
| ====+> 6
| Enter Number: 12
| ====+====|=> 12
| Enter Number: 50
| ====+====|====+====|====+====|====+====|====+====> 50
| Enter Number: 53
| ERROR: 53 is not in acceptable range.
| Enter Number: 33
| ====+====|====+====|====+====|==> 33
| Enter Number: 0
| 0
| Enter Number: 5
| ====> 5
| Enter Number: -1
 ------------------------------------------------
BarPlot – End Plot by User Request
```

Comment: Proper formatting helps a lot for correct diagnosis of errors: http://ideone.com/b3hgkX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for you to convert a number to a string in order to solve the problem.  The object `cout` can handle printing both numbers and strings without you needing to cast between them.

```
//example  
int number = 1;  
string str = "hello;
char c = '!';

//print hello1!
cout << str << number << c;
```

Here is a solution to the problem that does not require the need to cast an integer to a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //output inital prompt
    cout << "BarPlot – A Simple Bar Graph Plotter:\n";
    cout << "Input a number in range [0 50] or a negative number to terminate.\n\n";


    //read in input
    int number = 0;
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> number;

    //continue asking for input until a negative number is given
    while (number >= 0){

     for (int i = 1; i < number; ++i){

         //special symbol every 10th char
         if (i % 10 == 0) cout << "|";

         //special symbol every 5th char
         else if (i % 5 == 0) cout << "+";

         //every other char
         else cout << "=";
     }

      //print 0 or the number with an arrow before it
      if (number == 0) cout << 0;
      else cout << "> " << number << "\n";

      //re-ask for input
      cout << "\nEnter Number: ";
      cin >> number;
    }

    //output ending message
    cout << "BarPlot – End Plot by User Request\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```